# How can I have a user control have a dynamic height?

Tags: c#, winforms, user-controls

I'm making a control that has a pictureBox and a checkBox in there. I'm wrapping all of this into a user control in Windows Forms.

Instead of hard coding and finding the needed height, is there a way to have it have the height of it's parent controller with say 4px margin top and bottom?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can set the Dock property of the UserControl to Fill. This will make the UserControl fill the available space of the parent container (not used by other docked controls). If you also need padding, you can set the DockPadding property of the parent container like this:

```
container.DockPadding.Top = 4;
container.DockPadding.Bottom = 4;
```

However, if you don't want the control to take the Width of the parent container as well, you should use the Anchor property of the UserControl. Set it to Bottom and Top like this:

```
this.Anchor = AnchorStyles.Bottom | AnchorStyles.Top;
```

When it is added to the container, set it's `Location` and `Size` so its top is 4 pixels from the top of the container and its bottom is 4 pixels from the bottom. Then when the container resizes its Height, so will the UserControl.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can set the control's [`Anchor`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.anchor.aspx) property to `AnchorStyles.Top | AnchorStyles.Bottom` after resizing the control with the desired padding in the parent control.

> Anchoring a control to its parent control ensures that the anchored edges remain in the same position relative to the edges of the parent control when the parent control is resized.